# DevOps Pipeline test failing: Login.MainPage failed to load in 2 minutes

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, powerapps

I have set up a Azure DevOps Pipeline to run PowerApps Test Studio test cases, as per this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/test-studio-yaml-pipeline

The test case fails with:

```
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4674639Z Unable to connect to the remote server
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4675369Z Login.MainPage failed to load in 2 minutes using Cloud Identity Login.
```

Result details:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I can see the code where this is generated, however I do not know enough to determine if it is that Xpath that is wrong.

My PortalUrl value: https://make.powerapps.com

Repo forked from: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerAppsTestAutomation

[image]

Entire job details:

```
2024-02-13T04:30:07.6740734Z ##[section]Starting: Run Power Apps Test Automation Tests via Chrome
2024-02-13T04:30:07.6862360Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-13T04:30:07.6862762Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2024-02-13T04:30:07.6863094Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
2024-02-13T04:30:07.6863565Z Version      : 2.234.0
2024-02-13T04:30:07.6863672Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-02-13T04:30:07.6863834Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest
2024-02-13T04:30:07.6864011Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-13T04:30:08.3506953Z Running tests using vstest.console.exe runner.
2024-02-13T04:30:08.3507997Z ======================================================
<removed section to be within charater limit>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.4999111Z   <!-- Configurations that affect the  Test Automation -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.4999608Z   <RunConfiguration>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5000075Z     <MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5002311Z     <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5002838Z     <ResultsDirectory>..\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5003192Z 
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5003615Z     <!-- [x86] | x64    
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5004647Z       - You can also change it from menu Test, Test Settings, Default Processor Architecture -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5005289Z     <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5005598Z 
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5006056Z     <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5006582Z     <!-- TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework46</TargetFrameworkVersion -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5007143Z     <TargetFrameworkVersion>.NETFramework,Version=v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5007494Z 
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5007922Z     <!-- Path to Test Adapters -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5008448Z     <!--<TestAdaptersPaths>%SystemDrive%\Temp\foo;%SystemDrive%\Temp\bar</TestAdaptersPaths>-->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5008966Z   </RunConfiguration>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5009317Z 
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5009758Z   <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5010225Z   <DataCollectionRunSettings>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5010667Z     <DataCollectors>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5011399Z       <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5012107Z         <Configuration>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5012545Z           <CodeCoverage>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5012977Z             <ModulePaths>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5013408Z               <Exclude>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5013876Z                 <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestAutomation.*</ModulePath>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5014341Z               </Exclude>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5014765Z             </ModulePaths>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5015244Z             <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5015778Z             <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5016372Z             <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5016942Z             <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5017449Z             <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5017910Z           </CodeCoverage>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5018343Z         </Configuration>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5018775Z       </DataCollector>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5019232Z     </DataCollectors>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5019686Z   </DataCollectionRunSettings>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5020226Z   <!-- Parameters used by tests at runtime -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5020674Z   
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5021109Z   <!-- Adapter Specific sections -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5021549Z   
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5021968Z   <!-- MSTest adapter -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5022398Z   <!--
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5022816Z   <MSTest>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5023292Z     <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5023813Z     <CaptureTraceOutput>false</CaptureTraceOutput>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5024374Z     <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5024948Z     <DeploymentEnabled>False</DeploymentEnabled>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5025417Z     <AssemblyResolution>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5025903Z       <Directory path="D:\myfolder\bin\" includeSubDirectories="false"/>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5026386Z     </AssemblyResolution>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5026822Z   </MSTest>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5027237Z   -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5027655Z </RunSettings>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5027936Z 
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5241820Z Updated Run Settings:
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5243317Z <RunSettings>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5244002Z   <!-- Configurations that affect the  Test Automation -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5245511Z   <RunConfiguration>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5246038Z     <MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5246576Z     <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5247164Z     <ResultsDirectory>D:\a\_temp\..\TestResults\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5247876Z     <!-- [x86] | x64    
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5248450Z       - You can also change it from menu Test, Test Settings, Default Processor Architecture -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5249052Z     <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5249599Z     <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5250172Z     <!-- TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework46</TargetFrameworkVersion -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5250780Z     <TargetFrameworkVersion>.NETFramework,Version=v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5251342Z     <!-- Path to Test Adapters -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5251935Z     <!--<TestAdaptersPaths>%SystemDrive%\Temp\foo;%SystemDrive%\Temp\bar</TestAdaptersPaths>-->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5252514Z     <BatchSize>1000</BatchSize>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5253019Z   </RunConfiguration>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5253544Z   <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5254070Z   <DataCollectionRunSettings>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5254579Z     <DataCollectors>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5255367Z       <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5256142Z         <Configuration>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5256638Z           <CodeCoverage>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5257130Z             <ModulePaths>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5257721Z               <Exclude>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5258252Z                 <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestAutomation.*</ModulePath>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5258775Z               </Exclude>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5259256Z             </ModulePaths>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5259791Z             <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5260374Z             <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5260973Z             <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5261559Z             <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5262164Z             <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5262694Z           </CodeCoverage>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5263170Z         </Configuration>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5263665Z       </DataCollector>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5264171Z     </DataCollectors>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5264661Z   </DataCollectionRunSettings>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5265177Z   <!-- Parameters used by tests at runtime -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5265685Z   
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5266167Z   <!-- Adapter Specific sections -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5266669Z   <!-- MSTest adapter -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5267146Z   <!--
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5267601Z   <MSTest>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5268122Z     <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5268677Z     <CaptureTraceOutput>false</CaptureTraceOutput>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5269296Z     <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5269908Z     <DeploymentEnabled>False</DeploymentEnabled>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5270413Z     <AssemblyResolution>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5271015Z       <Directory path="D:\myfolder\bin\" includeSubDirectories="false"/>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5271542Z     </AssemblyResolution>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5272022Z   </MSTest>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5272486Z   -->
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5272952Z </RunSettings>
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5326985Z **************** Starting test execution *********************
2024-02-13T04:30:10.5411871Z [command]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe "@D:\a\_temp\gqxv0rpzvfw.tmp"
2024-02-13T04:30:11.1549592Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.11.0
2024-02-13T04:30:11.1550762Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2024-02-13T04:30:11.2859774Z vstest.console.exe "D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\bin\Debug\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.dll"
2024-02-13T04:30:11.2861452Z /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=PowerAppsTestAutomation"
2024-02-13T04:30:11.2862432Z /Settings:"D:\a\_temp\v3aq0m42sxo.tmp.runsettings"
2024-02-13T04:30:11.2863295Z /EnableCodeCoverage
2024-02-13T04:30:11.2863939Z /Logger:"trx"
2024-02-13T04:30:11.2864560Z /TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\1\s"
2024-02-13T04:30:16.8473922Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2024-02-13T04:30:21.9487883Z 3.0414
2024-02-13T04:30:22.1135770Z A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4635285Z   Failed RunTestAutomation [9 m 13 s]
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4643158Z   Error Message:
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4645529Z    Test method Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation threw exception: 
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4646394Z System.InvalidOperationException: Login failed after 3 attempts. Exception Details: System.Exception: Login page failed on login retry.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4647479Z    at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.<>c.<Login>b__12_1(IWebDriver f) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 188
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4648829Z    at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.SeleniumExtensions.WaitUntilVisible(IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan timeout, Action`1 successCallback, Action`1 failureCallback) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\Extensions\SeleniumExtensions.cs:line 737
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4649991Z    at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(IWebDriver driver, Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password, Action`1 redirectAction) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 169
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4651082Z    at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.DelegateBrowserCommand`5.ExecuteCommand(IWebDriver driver, Object[] params) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\DelegateBrowserCommand.cs:line 134
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4652246Z    at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4, T5 p5, T6 p6, T7 p7, T8 p8, T9 p9) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 136
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4653354Z    at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 60
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4654433Z    at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserPage.Execute[TResult,T1,T2,T3,T4](BrowserCommandOptions options, Func`6 delegate, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserPage.cs:line 230
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4655507Z    at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 73
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4664440Z    at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation() in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line 94
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4666336Z   Stack Trace:
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4669178Z       at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation() in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line 189
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4673816Z   Standard Output Messages:
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4674639Z  Unable to connect to the remote server
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4675369Z  Login.MainPage failed to load in 2 minutes using Cloud Identity Login.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4676321Z  Exception on Attempt #1: System.Exception: Login page failed using Cloud Identity Login.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4677224Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.<>c.<Login>b__12_3(IWebDriver f) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 160
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4678286Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.SeleniumExtensions.WaitUntilVisible(IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan timeout, Action`1 successCallback, Action`1 failureCallback) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\Extensions\SeleniumExtensions.cs:line 737
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4679417Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(IWebDriver driver, Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password, Action`1 redirectAction) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 141
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4681103Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.DelegateBrowserCommand`5.ExecuteCommand(IWebDriver driver, Object[] params) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\DelegateBrowserCommand.cs:line 134
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4682397Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4, T5 p5, T6 p6, T7 p7, T8 p8, T9 p9) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 136
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4683505Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 60
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4684566Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserPage.Execute[TResult,T1,T2,T3,T4](BrowserCommandOptions options, Func`6 delegate, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserPage.cs:line 230
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4685676Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 73
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4686681Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation() in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line 94
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4687461Z  Login failed after attempt #1.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4688102Z  UserID field is not visible. This should indicate a previous main page load failure.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4690324Z  Login.MainPage failed to load in 2 minutes on login retry.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4691226Z  Exception on Attempt #2: System.Exception: Login page failed on login retry.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4692091Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.<>c.<Login>b__12_1(IWebDriver f) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 188
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4693205Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.SeleniumExtensions.WaitUntilVisible(IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan timeout, Action`1 successCallback, Action`1 failureCallback) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\Extensions\SeleniumExtensions.cs:line 737
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4694378Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(IWebDriver driver, Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password, Action`1 redirectAction) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 169
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4696516Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.DelegateBrowserCommand`5.ExecuteCommand(IWebDriver driver, Object[] params) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\DelegateBrowserCommand.cs:line 134
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4699459Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4, T5 p5, T6 p6, T7 p7, T8 p8, T9 p9) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 136
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4704478Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 60
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4707508Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserPage.Execute[TResult,T1,T2,T3,T4](BrowserCommandOptions options, Func`6 delegate, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserPage.cs:line 230
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4709244Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 73
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4710447Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation() in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line 94
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4711235Z  Login failed after attempt #2.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4711862Z  UserID field is not visible. This should indicate a previous main page load failure.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4712564Z  Login.MainPage failed to load in 2 minutes on login retry.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4713280Z  Exception on Attempt #3: System.Exception: Login page failed on login retry.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4714087Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.<>c.<Login>b__12_1(IWebDriver f) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 188
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4716493Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.SeleniumExtensions.WaitUntilVisible(IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan timeout, Action`1 successCallback, Action`1 failureCallback) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\Extensions\SeleniumExtensions.cs:line 737
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4717876Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(IWebDriver driver, Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password, Action`1 redirectAction) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 169
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4718938Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.DelegateBrowserCommand`5.ExecuteCommand(IWebDriver driver, Object[] params) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\DelegateBrowserCommand.cs:line 134
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4721280Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4, T5 p5, T6 p6, T7 p7, T8 p8, T9 p9) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 136
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4722327Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 60
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4723271Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserPage.Execute[TResult,T1,T2,T3,T4](BrowserCommandOptions options, Func`6 delegate, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserPage.cs:line 230
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4724402Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 73
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4725367Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation() in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line 94
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4726201Z  Login failed after 3 attempts.
<removed lines for post character limit>
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4728966Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.SeleniumExtensions.WaitUntilVisible(IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan timeout, Action`1 successCallback, Action`1 failureCallback) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\Extensions\SeleniumExtensions.cs:line 737
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4730037Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(IWebDriver driver, Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password, Action`1 redirectAction) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 169
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4731120Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.DelegateBrowserCommand`5.ExecuteCommand(IWebDriver driver, Object[] params) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\DelegateBrowserCommand.cs:line 134
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4732172Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4, T5 p5, T6 p6, T7 p7, T8 p8, T9 p9) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 136
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4733204Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserCommand`1.Execute[T1,T2,T3,T4](IWebDriver driver, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserCommand.cs:line 60
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4734285Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserPage.Execute[TResult,T1,T2,T3,T4](BrowserCommandOptions options, Func`6 delegate, T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserPage.cs:line 230
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4735338Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.OnlineLogin.Login(Uri uri, SecureString username, SecureString password) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\OnlineLogin.cs:line 73
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4736291Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation() in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line 94
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4737223Z     at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation() in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line 133
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4738058Z  Current results directory location: D:\a\_temp\..\TestResults\TestResults\Deploy_VssAdministrator 2024-02-13 04_30_32\In
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4738736Z  
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4739273Z Debug Trace:
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4739919Z Attempting to authenticate to Maker Portal: https://make.powerapps.com/
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4744137Z  Value of userIdFieldVisible: True
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4745080Z  UserID field is visible. Proceeding with login.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4745661Z  Value of userIdFieldVisible: False
2024-02-13T04:39:47.4746223Z  Value of userIdFieldVisible: False
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5234170Z Results File: D:\a\_temp\..\TestResults\TestResults\VssAdministrator_fv-az904-212_2024-02-13_04_39_47.trx
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5283278Z Attachments:
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5284616Z   D:\a\TestResults\TestResults\b150c1e0-ad7b-4874-939d-a28099028add\VssAdministrator_fv-az904-212_2024-02-13.04_30_20.coverage
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5535877Z Total tests: 1
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5537507Z      Failed: 1
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5539272Z  Total time: 9.4207 Minutes
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5580077Z ##[error]Test Run Failed.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5749952Z Vstest.console.exe exited with code 1.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5756060Z **************** Completed test execution *********************
2024-02-13T04:39:47.5857970Z Test results files: D:\a\TestResults\TestResults\VssAdministrator_fv-az904-212_2024-02-13_04_39_47.trx
2024-02-13T04:39:47.8598200Z Created test run: 1000030
2024-02-13T04:39:47.8647052Z Publishing test results: 1
2024-02-13T04:39:47.9235820Z Publishing test results to test run '1000030'.
2024-02-13T04:39:47.9264523Z TestResults To Publish 1, Test run id:1000030
2024-02-13T04:39:47.9339572Z Test results publishing 1, remaining: 0. Test run id: 1000030
2024-02-13T04:39:48.6616552Z Published test results: 1
2024-02-13T04:39:48.6622836Z Publishing Attachments: 2
2024-02-13T04:39:49.0781653Z Execution Result Code 1 is non zero, checking for failed results
2024-02-13T04:39:49.1264768Z Completed TestExecution Model...
2024-02-13T04:39:49.1514611Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2024-02-13T04:39:49.1516971Z ##[error]Error: The process 'D:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.234.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1
2024-02-13T04:39:49.1526969Z ##[error]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2024-02-13T04:39:49.1632386Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Power Apps Test Automation Tests via Chrome
```

Comment: Multi-factor authentication isn't supported. Please check whether the account you are using to run the test in power app has MFA. You can go to the test summary, click the failed test case and check if there is any info in the attachments.

Comment: Thanks @ZiyangLiu-MSFT - I made sure the account was not MFA enabled (after earlier attempts showing that it did).  See added results screenshots in post now.  Something I have noticed, the error in the logs 'Unable to connect to the remote server', but no other info.  I am using CloudIdentity LoginMethod, if that helps.

Comment: Hi @dogowar, have you tried the repo shared by me? Did it also work for you?

Comment: Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT.  Apologies for the delayed reply, yes that repo has worked and I am past the point of logging in, thank you!  I am now working on the next error:

Comment: An error occurred during Test Run #1 of 1: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.TestAutomation.ReportResultsToDevOps(JObject jObject, Int32 testRunNumber) in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\TestAutomation.cs:line 166
at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation() in D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line 178

Comment: It's great to know the repo also works on your side. Since the original login issue has been resolved, it's suggested that you create a new question for your new error with the detailed error message and some screenshots to help clarify your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again @ZiyangLiu-MSFT, I have posted a new issue for above [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78065269/devops-pipeline-test-failing-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side using the official sample code.

It seems that there are some issues with the xpath selectors due to the changes of Power Apps homepage. You can use [this code from CesarCalvoCobo](https://github.com/CesarCalvoCobo/PowerAppsTestAutomation/tree/master) and it works fine. See the detailed info from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerAppsTestAutomation/issues/25#issuecomment-1676414472).
[image]