# DevOps Pipeline test failing: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (PowerApps test case)

Tags: powerapps

I have set up a Azure DevOps Pipeline to run PowerApps Test Studio test cases, as per this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/test-studio-yaml-pipeline

The test case fails with:

> An error occurred during Test Run #1 of 1:
> System.NullReferenceException: **Object reference not set to an instance**
> of an object. at
> Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.TestAutomation.ReportResultsToDevOps(JObject
> jObject, Int32 testRunNumber) in
> D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\TestAutomation.cs:line
> 166 at
> Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation()
> in
> D:\a\1\s\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line
> 178

I am not experienced enough to know how I need to analysis/rectify this issue, any advice welcomed.

The repo that I have used is: https://github.com/CesarCalvoCobo/PowerAppsTestAutomation/tree/master

**TestAutomation.cs**

```cs
    // Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    // Licensed under the MIT license.
    
    using Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    
    namespace Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api
    {
    
        /// <summary>
        ///   Test Automation methods.
        ///  </summary>
        public class TestAutomation
            : AppPage
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TestAutomation"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="browser">The browser.</param>
            public TestAutomation(InteractiveBrowser browser)
                : base(browser)
            {
            }
    
            public BrowserCommandResult<JObject> ExecuteTestAutomation(Uri uri, int testRunNumber, int maxWaitTimeInSeconds)
            {
                return this.Execute(GetOptions("Execute Test Automation"), driver =>
                {
                    // Navigate to TestSuite or TestCase URL
                    InitiateTest(driver, uri);
    
                    // Check for existence of permissions dialog (1st test load for user)
                    CheckForPermissionDialog(driver);
    
                    // Try to report the sessionId. There is a bit of a race condition here,
                    // so don't do this too close to fullscreen-app-host visibility or it 
                    // will fail to find Core or some other namespace.
                    TryReportSessionId(driver, testRunNumber);
    
                    // Wait for test completion and collect results
                    JObject testResults = WaitForTestResults(driver, maxWaitTimeInSeconds);
    
                    return testResults;
                });
            }
    
            public BrowserCommandResult<List<Uri>> GetTestURLs(string filePath)
            {
                return this.Execute(GetOptions("Get List of Test URLs"), driver =>
                {
                    //Replace encoded characters (%20) if present
                    if (filePath.Contains("%20"))
                    {
                        filePath = filePath.Replace("%20", " ");
                    }
                    // Initialize list of URLs
                    List<Uri> testUrlList = new List<Uri>();
    
                    // Read contents of json file
                    JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    
                    // Retrieve list of Test URLs
                    testUrlList = jObject["TestURLs"]?.ToObject<List<Uri>>();
    
                    return testUrlList;
                });
            }
    
            public class TestSuiteResult
            {
                public string TestSuiteId { get; set; }
                public string TestSuiteName { get; set; }
                public string TestSuiteDescription { get; set; }
                public long StartTime { get; set; }
                public long EndTime { get; set; }
                public int TestsPassed { get; set; }
                public int TestsFailed { get; set; }
            }
    
            public class TestCaseResult
            {
                public string TestSuiteId { get; set; }
                public string TestSuiteName { get; set; }
                public string TestSuiteDescription { get; set; }
                public string TestCaseId { get; set; }
                public string TestCaseName { get; set; }
                public string TestCaseDescription { get; set; }
                public string TestFailureMessage { get; set; }
                public long StartTime { get; set; }
                public long EndTime { get; set; }
                public bool Success { get; set; }
                public ArraySegment<string> Traces { get; set; }
    
            }
    
            internal void CheckForPermissionDialog(IWebDriver driver)
            {
                // Switch to default content
                driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    
                var dialogButtons = driver.WaitUntilAvailable(By.XPath(Elements.Xpath[Reference.TestAutomation.PermissionDialogButtons]), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
    
                if (dialogButtons != null)
                {
                    // Should be two buttons (Allow, Don't Allow)
                    var buttons = dialogButtons.FindElements(By.TagName("button"));
    
                    foreach (var b in buttons)
                    {
                        if (b.Text.Equals("Allow"))
                        {
                            b.Hover(driver, true);
                            b.Click(true);
                            b.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
                            driver.WaitForPageToLoad();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
            internal JObject WaitForTestResults(IWebDriver driver, int maxWaitTimeInSeconds)
            {
                JObject jsonResultString = new JObject();
                jsonResultString = driver.WaitForTestResults(maxWaitTimeInSeconds);
    
                return jsonResultString;
            }
    
            internal void InitiateTest(IWebDriver driver, Uri uri)
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(uri);
    
                // Wait for page to load
                driver.WaitForPageToLoad();
    
                // Wait for fullscreen-app-host
                driver.WaitUntilVisible(By.Id("fullscreen-app-host"));
                if (driver.IsVisible(By.Id("fullscreen-app-host")))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("fullscreen-app-host is visible.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("fullscreen-app-host is not visible.");
                }
            }
    
            public Tuple<int, int> ReportResultsToDevOps(JObject jObject, int testRunNumber)
            {
                var testExecutionMode = (int)jObject.GetValue("ExecutionMode");
    
                int passCount = 0;
                int failCount = 0;
    
    
                if (testExecutionMode == 0)
                {
                    // TestCase
                    var testCaseResults = jObject["TestCaseResult"]?.ToObject<TestCaseResult>();
    
                    if (testCaseResults.Success)
                    {
                        passCount = 1;
                        failCount = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        passCount = 0;
                        failCount = 1;
    
                    }
```

**RunTestAutomation.cs:**

```cs
    // Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    // Licensed under the MIT license.
    
    using Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser;
    using Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using System.Threading;
    
    namespace Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class TestAutomation
        {
            private static string _username = "";
            private static string _password = "";
            private static BrowserType _browserType;
            private static Uri _xrmUri;
            private static Uri _testAutomationUri;
            private static string _loginMethod;
            private static string _resultsDirectory = "";
            private static string _driversPath = "";
            private static string _usePrivateMode;
            private static string _testAutomationURLFilePath = "";
            private static int _globalTestCount = 0;
            private static int _globalPassCount = 0;
            private static int _globalFailCount = 0;
            private static int _testMaxWaitTimeInSeconds = 600;
    
            public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
    
            private static TestContext _testContext;
    
            [ClassInitialize]
            public static void Initialize(TestContext TestContext)
            {
           
    
    
    
                _testContext = TestContext;
                
                
                _username = _testContext.Properties["OnlineUsername"].ToString();
                _password = _testContext.Properties["OnlinePassword"].ToString();
                _xrmUri = new Uri(_testContext.Properties["OnlineUrl"].ToString());
                _loginMethod = _testContext.Properties["LoginMethod"].ToString();
                _resultsDirectory = _testContext.Properties["ResultsDirectory"].ToString();
                _browserType = (BrowserType)Enum.Parse(typeof(BrowserType), _testContext.Properties["BrowserType"].ToString());
                _driversPath = _testContext.Properties["DriversPath"].ToString();
                _usePrivateMode = _testContext.Properties["UsePrivateMode"].ToString();
                _testAutomationURLFilePath = _testContext.Properties["TestAutomationURLFilePath"].ToString();
                _testMaxWaitTimeInSeconds = Convert.ToInt16(_testContext.Properties["TestMaxWaitTimeInSeconds"]);
                            
            }
    
            [TestCategory("PowerAppsTestAutomation")]
            [Priority(1)]
            [TestMethod]
            public void RunTestAutomation()
            {
                BrowserOptions options = RunTestSettings.Options;
                options.BrowserType = _browserType;
                options.DriversPath = _driversPath;
    
                using (var appBrowser = new PowerAppBrowser(options))
                {
                    // Track current test iteration
                    int testRunCounter = 0;
                    // Track list of  Test Automation URLs
                    var testUrlList = appBrowser.TestAutomation.GetTestURLs(_testAutomationURLFilePath);
                    // Track total number of TestURLs
                    int testUrlCount = testUrlList.Value.Count();
    
                    foreach (Uri testUrl in testUrlList?.Value)
                    {
                        // Test URL
                        _testAutomationUri = testUrl;
                        testRunCounter += 1;
    
                        try
                        {
                            // if TestCounter > 1, authentication not required
                            if (testRunCounter <= 1)
                            {
                                //Login To PowerApps
                                Debug.WriteLine($"Attempting to authenticate to Maker Portal: {_xrmUri}");
    
                                for (int retryCount = 0; retryCount < Reference.Login.SignInAttempts; retryCount++)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        // See Authentication Types: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/user-account-management#authentication
                                        // CloudIdentity uses standard Office 365 sign-in service
                                        if (_loginMethod == "CloudIdentity")
                                        {
                                            appBrowser.OnlineLogin.Login(_xrmUri, _username.ToSecureString(), _password.ToSecureString());
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        // FederatedIdentity uses AD FS 2.0 or other Security Token Services
                                        else if (_loginMethod == "FederatedIdentity")
                                        {
                                            // Do Federated Login
                                            appBrowser.OnlineLogin.Login(_xrmUri, _username.ToSecureString(), _password.ToSecureString(), FederatedLoginAction);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        // FederatedIdentity scenario -- but DevOps agent is configured with SSO capability
                                        else if (_loginMethod == "PassThrough")
                                        {
                                            appBrowser.OnlineLogin.Login(_xrmUri);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        // Fallback to CloudIdentity experience if _loginMethod is not provided
                                        else
                                        {
                                            appBrowser.OnlineLogin.Login(_xrmUri, _username.ToSecureString(), _password.ToSecureString());
                                            break;
                                        }
    
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception exc)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine($"Exception on Attempt #{retryCount + 1}: {exc}");
    
                                        if (retryCount + 1 == Reference.Login.SignInAttempts)
                                        {
                                            // Login exception occurred, take screenshot
                                            _resultsDirectory = TestContext.TestResultsDirectory;
                                            string location = $@"{_resultsDirectory}\RunTestAutomation-LoginErrorAttempt{retryCount + 1}.jpeg";
    
                                            appBrowser.TakeWindowScreenShot(location, OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
                                            _testContext.AddResultFile(location);
    
                                            // Max Sign-In Attempts reached
                                            Console.WriteLine($"Login failed after {retryCount + 1} attempts.");
                                            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Login failed after {retryCount + 1} attempts. Exception Details: {exc}");
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            // Login exception occurred, take screenshot
                                            _resultsDirectory = TestContext.TestResultsDirectory;
                                            string location = $@"{_resultsDirectory}\RunTestAutomation-LoginErrorAttempt{retryCount + 1}.jpeg";
    
                                            appBrowser.TakeWindowScreenShot(location, OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
                                            _testContext.AddResultFile(location);
    
                                            //Navigate away and retry
                                            appBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
    
                                            Console.WriteLine($"Login failed after attempt #{retryCount + 1}.");
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
    
                            Console.WriteLine($"Power Apps  Test Automation Execution Starting Test #{testRunCounter} of {testUrlCount}");
    
                            // Initialize TestFrameworok results JSON object
                            JObject testAutomationResults = new JObject();
    
                            // Execute TestAutomation and return JSON result object
                            testAutomationResults = appBrowser.TestAutomation.ExecuteTestAutomation(_testAutomationUri, testRunCounter, _testMaxWaitTimeInSeconds);
    
                            #if DEBUG    
                            // Only output post execution screenshot in debug mode
                            _resultsDirectory = TestContext.TestResultsDirectory;
                            string location1 = $@"{_resultsDirectory}\TestRun{testRunCounter}-PostExecutionScreenshot.jpeg";
                            appBrowser.TakeWindowScreenShot(location1, OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            _testContext.AddResultFile(location1);
                            #endif
    
                            // Report Results to DevOps Pipeline                    
                            var testResultCount = appBrowser.TestAutomation.ReportResultsToDevOps(testAutomationResults, testRunCounter);
```

Comment: The issue is with the C# code of the project itself. You should first debug the code in Visual Studio on your local machine and ensure you can run the tests in Visual Studio. Then you can try to move the project to Azure DevOps to run build and test in pipelines.

Comment: From the error message, it seems that the object referenced in the code is not instantiated.

Comment: I opened the same demo in Visual Studio on my local machine and can reproduce the same error when running the tests. So, the issue is with the C# code itself as stated above.

Comment: Thanks @BrightRan-MSFT, I have reached out to the owner of the repo, will see if there is anything that comes back.